# Test file download, but suppress file contents being output on the command line

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm testing routes for downloading files in my Symfony application and everything is going fine, except for the ugly output of the PDF contents on the command line.

For example I want to check that certain user role has access rights to download a PDF file:

```
$this->client->request('GET', '/media/download/1');
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

When this part of the test is hit, the contents of the PDF are print out on the command line, like this:

> 31 / 31 (100%)%PDF-1.4 %äüöß 2 0 obj <> stream x��TKk�@����s��<�%0�8�
>                          ��1�PzR����K�~��"j 9��ݙ�of��4
>               _���c(��C���������@|�c�T�3%��������p�-�.

This is just for illustration, the actual output is much longer.

This is a general issue and happens with other MIME types too.

Is there any possibility to suppress the output?

Comment: `ob_start()/ob_clean()`

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you very much! It works! Would you please write a full answer with explanation helpful to other users too? Then I can upvote/accept it.

Comment: can you please share your complete code that how you fixed that issue. There was no understanding for the third person.

Comment: @MudassarZahid Please check the answer from u_mulder. That's exactly how I've solved it.

Comment: @cezar can you please check my recent asked question, which is similar to your question. that answer was not helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in other cases when you don't need output right here and right now, you can buffer it with `ob_` functions, for example:

```
// start buffering
ob_start();
$this->client->request('GET', '/media/download/1');
// and as you really don't care about output - just clean it
ob_clean();
// use 
// $contents = ob_get_clean();
// if you still need output
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

**Update**: to avoid error message like

> Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

use `ob_end_clean()` instead of `ob_clean()`.

Comment: At first I thought this solves the problem completely as the output is cleaned. However the test is marked as risky and I get the following message: `Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers`. Have you got any further hint?

Comment: Try to use `ob_end_clean` instead of `ob_clean`.